An application of the Gleason-Montgomery-Zippin Theorem
In the book How groups grow by Avinoam Mann, the author cites the following theorem attributed to Gleason-Montgomery-Zippin.

Theorem 6.4 (Gleason–Montgomery–Zippin: solution of Hilbert’s Fifth Problem [Ka 95, MZ 55]) Let T be a finite dimensional, locally compact, connected and locally connected, homogeneous metric space. Then the group of isometries of T can be given the structure of a Lie group with finitely many components.

Looking at the cited references, I cannot find any statement of the form above. From what I understand, it would suffice to show that $Isom(T)$ is locally Euclidean with finitely many components, but I do not see how that follows from the hypotheses.
Can someone familiar with the literature surrounding Hilbert's fifth problem shed some light on the matter?

You did not look hard enough, it is in section 6.3, Corollary on page 243 of Montgomery-Zippin.

Corollary (from 6.3): If a locally compact group G satisfying (A) acts faithfully and transitively on a locally compact, connected, finite-dimensional space, then G is a Lie group.
(A) G is the limit of a countable inverse sequence of Lie groups $\cdots \to G_2\to G_1$ where the maps $G{i+1}\to G_i$ are continuous with compact kernel._
I don't see why the isometry group in the question satisfies (A) nor why it has finitely-many components.

It is a locally compact separable Hausdorff group, hence, it contains an open subgroup which satisfies (A), this is the main result of Montgomery-Zippin. Already this open subgroup acts transitively on $T$. As for finitely many components, take a look at the fiber bundle $G_x\to G\to T$ and note that  is connected and $G_x$  is a compact Lie group. I can add more detail if this is not enough.

@MoisheKohan, thanks for the comment, more detail would be appreciated (topological groups really aren't my thing). 1) It seems the Corollary applies to an open subgroup of $Isom(T)$ and not the entire group, yet Theorem 6.4 says $Isom(T)$ is a Lie group. 2) Why is $G_x$ a compact Lie group? If you post your reply as an answer, I can accept it.

Ok, I will write a proper answer later. But check Tao's book, see if he includes a proof. It is, by now, a standard argument, used in relation to Gromov's theorem on groups of polynomial growth.
